# Asemejar el estilo de un select en diferentes navegadores

Tags: css3

Tengo un `select` el cual tiene unos estilos establecidos. El problema es que lo visualizo de diferente forma en **Chrome** y en **Firefox** y me gustaría tener un estilo al menos similar o parecido.

El código que uso es:

```css
#seleccionar{
  background-color:transparent;
  color:#259af0;
  text-transform: none;
  border:none;
}

#seleccionar:focus{
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="seleccionar">
  <option>Prueba 1</option>
  <option>Prueba 2</option>
</select>
```

En Chrome se visualiza de está manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que en Firefox de está otra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Con que estilos puedo asimilarlas en diferentes navegadores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `selects` tienden a cambiar mucho su apariencia de navegador a navegador.

Dependiendo de tus necesidades de soporte de navegadores puedes utilizar `appearance` que es soportado por la [mayoría de navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance) a excepción de IE9 (para variar) con sus respectivos *vendor prefix*.

Es la única forma que he logrado que todos se vean uniformes en diferentes navegadores (excepto en aquel que no debe ser nombrado) utilizando solo css

```css
select:not([multiple]) {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Caret_down_font_awesome.svg/1024px-Caret_down_font_awesome.svg.png") no-repeat 100% center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
}

#seleccionar {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #259af0;
  text-transform: none;
  border: none;
}

#seleccionar:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="seleccionar">
  <option>Prueba 1</option>
  <option>Prueba 2</option>
</select>
```