# No puedo modificar la caja desplazable de un select

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda que llevo ya un tiempo sin poder resolver, y es que yo no puedo modificar la caja desplazable que sale al clickear un select y me gustaría saber como hacer para poder modificarla, he intentado seleccionando el option pero no pasa absolutamente nada, llevo ya dos dias buscando en la red y no he conseguido respuesta, si alquien pudiera ayudarme le estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Me gustaría poder ayudarte. Podrías mostrar el código que tienes y qué quieres modificar, para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Te sirven unas capturas? Ya que la verdad es que la caja de la que hablo no la consigo como tal como un elemento

Comment: @AdrianAguilar la cajas de select vienen por defecto de un color en su defecto un azul, es imposible cambiar el color de estos ya que vienen predeterminado por el sistema operativo.

Comment: utliza las herramientas de **sackoverflow** para `mostrar tu código`. sin mostrar código es dificil ayudar.

Comment: @TheVicious entiendo, entonces muchas gracias por la ayuda y la atención!, supongo que tendré que aprender a usar bootstrap ya que por lo que tengo entendido ahí si se puede modificar

Comment: @AdrianAguilar ¿qué es exactamente lo que quieres modificar? No termina de quedar claro en la pregunta. Añade el código que tengas, una imagen de cómo quieres que se vea, y puede que podamos echarte una mano. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Tu pregunta puede ser parecida a [Asemejar el estilo de un select en diferentes navegadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/167575/250) o [¿como cambiar los colores por defecto de los options de un select?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48671/250). Mira a ver si te vale alguna de esas. Si no, hay [otras publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=appearance+select) que igual te pueden servir de guía.